# Constructing multidimensional array for desired JSON output for timeline.js

Tags: php, json, timeline.js

The [timelineJS](http://www.timeline.verite.co) requires a specified JSON format. So far with this php code I'm able to generate an output like this below:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT filename, data AS added,  f.image as media, f.info_hash AS hash, c.name AS category FROM xbtit_files f LEFT JOIN xbtit_categories c ON f.category = c.id WHERE f.uploader =  '2' ORDER BY added DESC"); 

$json_arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { 
if (strlen(htmlspecialchars($row[filename])) > 30)
  $t_name  = substr(htmlspecialchars($row[filename]), 0, 30)."...";
else
  $t_name  = htmlspecialchars($row[filename]);

$row_arr['credit'] = $row['hash'];
$row_arr['caption'] = $row['category'];
$row_arr['media'] = $row['media'];
$row_arr['headline'] = $t_name;
$row_arr['startDate'] = $row[added];
array_push($json_arr,$row_arr);
} 
$json = '{"timeline":
    {
        "headline":"UPLOADER1",
        "type":"default",
        "text":"Show all uploads of this uploader",
        "asset": {
            "media":"http://localhost/torrent/torrentimg/49ac3aa95ec6d2ae56772a158b41d4aa62a7b78c.jpg",
            "credit":"Credit Name Goes Here",
            "caption":"Caption text goes here"
            },
        "date":
            '.json_encode($json_arr).'

    }}';
echo $json;
```

This gives output like this:

```
{
"timeline": {
    "headline": "UPLOADER1",
    "type": "default",
    "text": "Show all uploads of this uploader",
    "asset": {
        "media": "http://localhost/torrent/torrentimg/49ac3aa95ec6d2ae56772a158b41d4aa62a7b78c.jpg",
        "credit": "Credit Name Goes Here",
        "caption": "Caption text goes here"
    },
    "date": [
        {
            "headline": "Avatar",
            "startDate": "2012-06-26 12:03:13"
        },
        {
            "headline": "Rio BRRIP x264-1080p-2011",
            "startDate": "2012-06-26 11:59:19"
        },
        {
            "headline": "The Number 23 (2007)",
            "startDate": "2012-06-26 11:50:44"
        },
        {
            "headline": "Fate Stay night",
            "startDate": "2012-06-26 11:41:01"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

How would I be able to get something like this:

```
{
"timeline":
{
    "headline":"UPLOADER 1",
    "type":"default",
    "text":"Name of the Uploader",
    "startDate":"2012,1,26",
    "date": [
        {
            "startDate":"2012,2,30",
            "headline":"Hanky Panky (Torrent Name)",
            "text":"<p>Some description of the torrent.</p>",
            "asset":
            {
                "media":"Poster.jpg",
                "credit":"",
                "caption":""
            }
        },
        {
            "startDate":"2012,2,18",
            "headline":"Torrent Name 2",
            "text":"This movie was released on... The actors are....",
            "asset":
            {
                "media":"Poster1.jpg",
                "credit":"",
                "caption":"Directed and Edited by Matt Mayer, Produced by Seth Keim, Written by Eliot Glazer. Featuring Eliot and Ilana Glazer, who are siblings, not married."
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Note that: there's JSON objects inside the object asset. How this could be achieved?
Can anybody help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by tinkering with the arrays as suggested by [user1660584](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1660584/user1660584). Thanks.

The multidimentional array will look like this:

```
$c['timeline']['headline']= 'uploader1';
$c['timeline']['type'] = 'Default Type';
$c['timeline']['text'] = 'Some Text about the uploader';
$c['timeline']['asset']['media'] = 'torrentimg/49ac3aa95ec6d2ae56772a158b41d4aa62a7b78c.jpg';
$c['timeline']['asset']['caption'] = 'Assets consists of media files, caption and categories';
$c['timeline']['date'] = array(array(
    "startDate"=>'asfsf as fa',
    "headline"=>'kjahdas a',
    "text"=>'ahidahs kahs',
    "asset" => array(
                "media"=> 'image.png',
                "credit"=> 'Category',
                "caption"=> 'Some Text'
    )
),array(
    "startDate"=>'asfsf as fa',
    "headline"=>'kjahdas a',
    "text"=>'ahidahs kahs',
    "asset" => array(
                "media"=> 'image.png',
                "credit"=> 'Category',
                "caption"=> 'Some Text'
    )
));
echo json_encode($c);
```

I just have to put it inside a loop with the sql relult.

Answer (score 2):

json_encode() can convert PHP multi-dimensional array into a json string without problem, so create PHP array with desired structure and call json_encode on it.

Comment: That's where I'm stuck. I can;t figure out how I would construct the multidimensional array.

Comment: well, that makes it completely different question.

$a = array();
$a['firstKey'] = array();
$a['firstKey']['secondKey'] = 'theValue';